# Magento 2 : InstallData.php Does Not Seems to be Running While setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, attributes, setup, installdata

In custom module, I have `InstallSchema.php` and a `InstallData.php` files.

`InstallSchema.php` seems to be running fine, both tables declared in file are created.

But with the `InstallData.php` nothing happens.

**InstallData.php**

```
    <?php
namespace VVV\Comercial\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

  protected $customerSetupFactory;


  private $attributeSetFactory;

    private $categorySetupFactory;

    private $eavSetupFactory;

  public function __construct(
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
    AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
    EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
    CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
  ) {
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
      $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
      $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
  }


  public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
  {

      $setup->startSetup();

    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    //$customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
      $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

      $eavSetup->addAttribute(
          Customer::ENTITY,
          'is_commercial',
          [
              'type' => 'int',
              'label' => __('Commercial user'),
              'input' => 'boolean',
              'required' => false,
              'sort_order' => 100,
              'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
              //'group' => 'General Information',
              //'is_used_in_grid' => true,
              //'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
              //'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
          ]
      );


      $setup->endSetup();

    /*$customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'is_commercial', [
      'type' => 'int',
      'label' => __('Commercial user'),
      "default" => 0,
      'input' => 'boolean',
      'required' => false,
      'visible' => true,
      'user_defined' => true,
      'sort_order' => 1000,
      'position' => 1000,
      'system' => 0,
    ]);

    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'is_commercial')
      ->addData([
      'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
      'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
      'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
    ]);

    $attribute->save();*/
  }
}
```

The attribute is not created in  `eav_attribute` table, also `setup_module` table not filled `data_version` columna when running setup:upgrade.

There is a way to debug a bit more this kind of stuff?

Why `InstallData.php` does not seems to be running.

For tests, I delete the row in `setup_table` then run setup:upgrade.

I have to do something else to be able to run the `InstallData.php`?

Comment: Have you try to create custom attribute, right?

Comment: I'm trying to create the customer attribute on module install. I even put an exit(); in there but same. Also why does not get filled  the column  `data_version` in the `setup_module` on setup:upgrade?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this issue? I am running into the same problem myself on Magento 2.2.1.

Comment: No, sorry! Try the comment of jdhildeb it may work. setup:di:compuile could give you errors of modules even before installing them

Comment: Please post the content of your InstallSchema.php file and also the row containing your module from the setup_module table.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following way:

```
namespace VVV\Comercial\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Class InstallData
 *
 * @package VVV\Comercial\Setup
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        // Add new customer attribute
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'is_commercial',
            [

                'label'                 => 'Commercial user',
                'input'                 => 'boolean',
                'required'              => false,
                'sort_order'            => 900,
                'visible'               => true,
                'system'                => false,
                'is_used_in_grid'       => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid'    => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => false
            ]
        );

        // add attribute to form
        /** @var  $attribute */
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'is_commercial');
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer']);
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

**Make sure your module is deleted from setup_module table before run setup:upgrade**

For debug, you can user **error_log** or **magento log system** for checking, it's running or not when you install module.

Comment: deleting from setup_module worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i found that i was missing setup_version in etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Name_ModuleName" setup_version="0.0.1">
</module>
```

if you etc/module is right then run:
DELETE FROM setup_module where module = "Module_Name"

run bin/magento setup:upgrade

Answer (score 1):

You can change the version of your module or delete the record from the `setup_module` table.

Then run `setup:upgrade` and `setup:di:compile`

Answer (score 0):

If InstallData.php does not seem to be running, make sure you run

`bin/magento setup:di:compile`

BEFORE you run `setup:upgrade`.